# Javascript .load not working consistently, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript

I need another set (or several sets) of eyes to see what I am missing.  I am working on the following website: http://www.nbtc.org/nv2

I am dynamically loading content by using .load, when a link is clicked, the relevant code from a .php file is loaded into an empty div that is located on top of the home screen.

All of the links on the top menubar work perfectly, the couple of links that I have populated on the left vertical menubar work great as well. Try Drive & Park - Cashkey for an example.  FYI - The 'Home' link works.

However, the 'Free Carpool/Vanpool Matching, Transit Info' link that is on the home screen won't work.  The code is formatted identically to the other links that do work.  I am sure there is something in how I have the different parts organized that is keeping it from working, I just don't see it.

The link is good, choosing 'Request Information' - 'Rideshare Info' from the left menu brings up the same exact page with no issue.

Thanks in advance for your help!

UPDATE!! Sorry!!  It would help if I actually put the right website.  It's actually http://www.nbtc.org/nv2. (I fixed the link at the top)

As to specific code, the links in the horizontal and vertical menubars are variations of the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#menubar").on("click", ".target", function(event{event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load(event.target.href);
});
</script>
```

So, the link has the class ".target" which then loads the linked php into the empty div '#content' that is on top of the main home page.  Other than the ID, the script is identical. The left menu's script says '#leftmenu1' instead of '#menubar'.

So the problem is with the 'Free carpool matching' button.  It sits in the '#splash' div which sits behind the empty '#content' div, it uses this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#splash").on("click", ".target", function(event){event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load(event.target.href);
});
</script>
```

It's the same script, but it doesn't work!  Check out the page, the finished links in the two menubars work perfectly.  I know its not the link itself, because one of the buttons on the left menu links to the same content with no problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Please include the relevant portion of the code that isn't working rather than make people try to go find it in a web page.  This also makes your question useful in the future when the web page has been fixed/changed.  Plus none of the problem links you refer to in your question seem to be on the linked page.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the tip, I updated the question and figured it out, though I don't know why the fix actually fixed it...

Answer (score 2):

After making the corrections to the Javascript it still didn't work.  So, I decided to systematically remove every part of the div until it would work.  That did the trick, that is to say I got it to work, as to why it works, I hope someone can enlighten me.

Here is the original version of the div:

```
<div id="cpmatch"><a class="target" href="ridematchapp.php"><span>    
<h1>FREE</h1>Carpool/Vanpool Matching,<br>Transit Info</span></a></div>
```

With css it makes a large round button, the word 'Free' was on the first line and formatted large and italicized.  The 'span' was used so I could make the rest of the text larger than the normal text on the screen but smaller than the 'Free' and not italicized.

IT WAS THE SPAN!  I rearranged the css making it simpler but formatting the text the same, removed the span so the div now looks like this:

```
<div id="cpmatch"><a class="target" href="ridematchapp.php">    
<h1>FREE</h1>Carpool/Vanpool Matching,<br>Transit Info</a></div>
```

It works!  I don't know why, but it does.

The css I had on the span was minor text formatting.  Even after I deleted the '#cpmatch span' from the css file it still wouldn't work, so the formatting had nothing to do with it.

By the way, is it kosher to use the h1 tag, I am reformating it with css, so it's taking the place of a span, but if I put a span in instead the button wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your scripts begin with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

after the `<script>` tag? Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menubar").on("click", ".target", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#content").load(event.target.href);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I originally did have it that way when the javascript was in the head, now I have all the javascript at the end of the page in the body.  I am by no means an expert, but my research suggested the document.ready function wasn't necessary when I include the script at the end of the page.  Right?

Comment: It's necessary in your case. $(document).ready is called when the DOM is ready. You are accessing DOM elements (ids #menubar and #content), so you have to do it this way. The way you are doing it right now is assigning events to non-existing targets.

Comment: I really appreciate you explaining it, I will make the change and see if that corrects it.

Comment: Alejandro, I was finally able to make the correction that you suggested, but it did not fix it.  Please see my update above, I figured it out, it is strange.